# Difference between inverse functions and inverse images

Tags: calculus

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be the function $f(x)=x^2$. Find $f^{-1}([-1,2])$.

Since the inverse function is not defined (since $f$ is not injective), how do I solve this?

Obviously, the soution is a set (a subset or $\mathbb{R}$), but since the "codomain" of $f$ is $[0,\infty)$, I don't see what values we are looking at... $f$ don't take on negative values, as far as I can see...

(Obviously, $\sqrt{-1}=i$, but this is not the answer...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f:A\to B$ is a function and $B'\subseteq B$ then the inverse image of $B'$ under $f$ is defined as the set
$$f^{-1}(B')=\{x\in A:f(x)\in B'\}$$
In your case (assuming $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$),
$$f^{-1}([-1, 2]) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: x^2 \in [-1, 2]\}$$
It's easy to see that this happens when $x\in [0, \sqrt 2]$. Notice that when we are talking about the inverse image of a set $B'$, it is not necessary for every element of $B'$ to be in the image of $f$ (i.e. $f$ doesn't have to be onto $B'$).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was the "not need to be onto" part that confused me... from calculus-level and below I'm used to bijective functions (on the predefined domain).